# implicit vs. default assignment operator in C++

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

In C++, if I have a class/struct with assignable elements, I would normally not provide an assignment operator. However, there is also the option to define it as default using `C& operator=(C const&) = default;` (in the header file).

Is there any difference between the two approaches, apart from the fact that explicit definition makes it possible to make the operator private or protected?

And is this the same for other elements that can be either omitted or set to `default`, such as (copy) constructors?

Comment: Please clarify your use of nomenclature. When you say "define it and set it to default", do you mean `class C { C& operator=(C const&) = default; };` where it is decalred as defaulted.... or `class C { C& operator=(C const&); }; C& C::operator=(C const&) = default;` where it is declared in the class and then defaulted in its definition?

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_assignment

Comment: I think one difference between implicit and defaulted may be the effect on the rule of five/zero, so I'm eager to read a proper answer of this good question.

Comment: I can't find anything in the Standard that says either that they are guaranteed to be the same or that they can be different - with one exception: the exception specifier.

Comment: ... best I can find is: *Explicitly-defaulted functions and implicitly-declared functions are collectively called defaulted functions, and the implementation shall provide implicit definitions for them* (C++17, 11.4.2 #5)

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica: I meant the former and updated the question accordingly.

Comment: @MichalKaut note there _is_ a difference in what Storyteller is mentioning in regards to inlining. This doesn't always matter but it can matter a lot in regards to destructors in particular. Not specifying or defaulting can be inlined. Specifying and defaulting in the implementation file cannot (except through link time code gen).

Comment: _Is there any difference between the two approaches_ With a user-declared copy ass. operator, there will be no implicitly declared move-ctor and move ass. operator

Comment: @LanguageLawyer Maybe you should post that as an answer? I was considering doing so, a few minutes ago, until I saw your comment.